# Float left, vertical align middle, and display table cell does't work

Tags: html, css

I want image in left side and content in right side. But the image not in the middle when I using float:left, maybe someone of you give me a solution?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap-shop"><div class="pro-img">
<img src="http://tshop.r10s.com/c18/f19/b968/3a87/a005/a662/e954/11bee5abd6005056ae13f2.jpg?_ex=125x125"/></div>

<div class="kanan">
<div class="discount">
  40%
</div> <!-- end discount -->

<div class="judul">
  beauty korea beauty korea beauty korea beauty korea beauty korea
</div>

<div class="harga-coret">Rp<del>1,000,000</del></div>
    <div class="harga-asli">Rp 500,000</div>

    <div class="bonusRsp">
        300,000
    </div>

<span class="go-shop">
            Rincian Produk
        </span>
```

CSS:

```
   .wrap-pop{

    margin-top:10px;
}

.wrap-shop{
        border:solid #eaeaea 1px;
        width:100%;
        height:130px;

}

/* here is problem */

.pro-img{
    padding:2px;
    border:1px solid red;
    --float:left;   
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    background: #fff;
    background-size:135px 100px;
    --border-right:2px solid #bf0000;
}

.pro-img img{
    max-width:125px;
    max-height:125px;
    border:1px solid yellow;


}

.kanan{
    border:3px solid brown;

}

.judul{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:145px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    color:black;
    font-size:12px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.discount{
    border:1px solid yellow;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
}

.discount::before { 
    content: "Diskon ";
}


.bonusRsp{
    color:#bf0000;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font-size:12px;
}

.bonusRsp::before { 
    content: "Bonus ";
    color:black;
    font-size:12px;
}

.bonusRsp::after { 
    content: " Poin";
    color:black;
    font-size:12px;
}

.discount a{
    color:yellow;
}

.harga-coret{
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-left:150px;
}

.harga-coret a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.harga-asli{
    font-size:15px;
    color:#bf0000;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:150px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

.harga-asli a{
    color:#bf0000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.go-shop{
    border:1px solid #bf0000;
    border-radius:2px;
    width:120px;
    color:#bf0000;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:9px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;

}

.judul a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.go-shop a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/m6snbftt/2/

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI now used to this code

**Define**

```
.kanan{display:table-cell;}
```

**Remove** `float left` `.pro-img`

Demo

```css
.kanan{display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;}


.wrap-pop{
 
 margin-top:10px;
}
.wrap-shop{
  border:solid #eaeaea 1px;
  width:100%;
  height:130px;
  
}

/* here is problem */

.pro-img{
 padding:2px;
 border:1px solid red;
 vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
 width:125px;
 height:125px;
 background: #fff;
 background-size:135px 100px;
 --border-right:2px solid #bf0000;
}

.pro-img img{
 max-width:125px;
 max-height:125px;
 border:1px solid yellow;


}

.kanan{
 border:3px solid brown;
 
}

.judul{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-left:145px;
 text-transform:capitalize;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin-bottom:1px;
 color:black;
 font-size:12px;
 height:30px;
 border:1px solid red;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.discount{
 border:1px solid yellow;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:12px;
}

.discount::before { 
    content: "Diskon ";
}


.bonusRsp{
 color:#bf0000;
 margin-top:4px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 font-size:12px;
}

.bonusRsp::before { 
    content: "Bonus ";
 color:black;
 font-size:12px;
}

.bonusRsp::after { 
    content: " Poin";
 color:black;
 font-size:12px;
}

.discount a{
 color:yellow;
}

.harga-coret{
 margin-top:5px;
 font-size:11px;
 margin-left:150px;
}

.harga-coret a{
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.harga-asli{
 font-size:15px;
 color:#bf0000;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-left:150px;
 margin-bottom:2px;
}

.harga-asli a{
 color:#bf0000;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.go-shop{
 border:1px solid #bf0000;
 border-radius:2px;
 width:120px;
 color:#bf0000;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:white;
 margin-left:9px;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:12px;
 
}

.judul a{
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.go-shop a{
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-pop">

<div class="wrap-shop">
  <div class="pro-img">
    <img src="http://tshop.r10s.com/c18/f19/b968/3a87/a005/a662/e954/11bee5abd6005056ae13f2.jpg?_ex=125x125"/>
  </div> <!-- end pro-img -->
  
  <div class="kanan">
    <div class="discount">
      40%
    </div> <!-- end discount -->
    
    <div class="judul">
      beauty korea beauty korea beauty korea beauty korea beauty korea
    </div>
    
    <div class="harga-coret">Rp<del>1,000,000</del></div>
  <div class="harga-asli">Rp 500,000</div>
  
  <div class="bonusRsp">
   300,000
  </div>
    
    <span class="go-shop">
    Rincian Produk
   </span>
    
  </div>
  
</div> <!-- end wrap shop -->

</div> <!-- end wrap-pop -->
```

Answer (score 1):

`--float:left;`, change it to `float:left;` to work. **Update:** Add top padding and decrease the height.

Please try following:

```
.pro-img{
  padding-top:15px;
  padding-right:2px;
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;   
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width:125px;
  height:111px;
  background: #fff;
  background-size:135px 100px;
  --border-right:2px solid #bf0000;
}
```

Comment: yes, but the image not in the middle in border red. When I didn't use float left, the image is in the middle

Comment: What do you mean by middle? if you remove the float, the image stay on the left but the rest of the contents appears in the below of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `display: table;` class `.wrap-shop`

https://jsfiddle.net/m6snbftt/5/

Comment: nice thats a solution, solved... Thank you Lalji Tadhani :)